# iOS localized string constants for time symbols ("MINUTE(S)", "HOUR(S)" etc.)

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I am writing an app which need to show dates with corresponding time symbols like "hours", "minutes" etc.
There are cool localized constants for months and weekdays names in NSDateFormatter like monthSymbols (January, February etc). However, I can't find anything like this for such symbols as "hour", "minute" itself. Does such constants exists or I should create and localize these symbols by myself?

UPD:
My goal is a text for label under "30" - only localized "MIN" string without any numbers I should get rid of before placing text from date formatter in the label at the bottom.
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the details of what you need, `NSDateComponentsFormatter` might be the solution. It includes `NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleSpellOut`, which renders strings in formats like “One hour, ten minutes”.

Update: After reading comments I'm still not sure what kind of formatting you really need. But hopefully this will be a useful example:

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyle.Full
formatter.allowedUnits = [ NSCalendarUnit.Minute, NSCalendarUnit.Hour ]

let date = NSDate()

let dateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([.Minute, .Hour], fromDate: date)
let dateString = formatter.stringFromDateComponents(dateComponents)
```

At this point, `dateString` will be something like "15 hours, 11 minutes".

Comment: Yes, it might be helpful, however I need only 'hour' or 'minute' and your solution leaves me with need to separate value and symbols, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe. Could you describe in a little more detail what you're trying to do here?

Comment: My goal is a label with minutes (number) and another little label with time symbol below.

Answer (score 10):

If you need just the **min** string localized you can use a `MeasurementFormatter()`

```
let measurementFormatter: MeasurementFormatter = {
    let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    measurementFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    measurementFormatter.unitOptions = .providedUnit
    measurementFormatter.unitStyle = .short        
    return measurementFormatter
}()

label.text = measurementFormatter.string(from: UnitDuration.minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very pretty, but works:

```
var localizedMinutesShort: String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.unitsStyle = .short
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.minute]

    let date = Date()

    let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: date)
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: dateComponents)
    
    return dateString?.filter { $0.isLetter } ?? "min"
}
```

Inspired by @Tom Harrington solution.